# Redirect images with .htacces - keeping the url

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to redirect all images calls (.png,.jpg,.jpeg) from a specific folder, to another folder.
example.

```
www.somesite.com/dev/folder1/image1.jpg -> redirect to -> www.somesite.com/folder1/image1.jpg
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)$ http://www.somesite.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change the 302 to a 301 for a permanent redirect once you confirm it works (if the images will be moving permanently)